# How to convert foreach to if in Php

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I want to convert foreach to if statement because mysql query returns only one row.So i want to use if instead of foreach

```
    $db = new db();
    $db -> serverconnection();

    $item = $_GET["name"];

    $query = "SELECT c.firstname,c.phonenumber,c.address FROM `order` o,customerdetails c WHERE o.ordercode = '$item' AND c.sno=o.customerid";

        $results = $db->selectQuery($query);


            foreach ($results as $customerdetails)
            {
                $orderidDetail = $customerdetails['customerid'];
                echo $customerdetails["firstname"];
                echo $customerdetails["phonenumber"];
                echo $customerdetails["address"];       
           }
```

Comment: What is the purpose if it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [current](http://php.net/current).

```
$customerdetails = current($results);
if($customerdetails)
    {
    $orderidDetail = $customerdetails['customerid'];
    echo $customerdetails["firstname"];
    echo $customerdetails["phonenumber"];
    echo $customerdetails["address"];       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
foreach ($results as $customerdetails)
{
    $orderidDetail = $customerdetails['customerid'];
    echo $customerdetails["firstname"];
    echo $customerdetails["phonenumber"];
    echo $customerdetails["address"];
```

}

to

```
if(isset($results[0]))
{
    $orderidDetail = $results[0]['customerid'];
    echo $results[0]["firstname"];
    echo $results[0]["phonenumber"];
    echo $results[0]["address"];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
if (count($results) == 1) { 
   ... single row of results ...
} else {
   foreach(...) { ... multiple rows ...}
}
```

perhaps?

But if you KNOW the query will only ever return one row, then you don't really need the if/foreach at all anyways.